Mouse not responding/recognized
I've recently bought a RGB wired mouse and it was working fine.
But after removing the mouse from my laptop and reconnecting it again I noticed that it wasn't responding.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the drivers but it didn't work.
Tried to plug it into another usb port, nope.

But when i restarted my laptop it started working again.
So if I start my laptop with the mouse already plugged it works as normal, but if i start my laptop without the mouse and then plug in the mouse my laptop recognizes the mouse as Unknown device.
So what should I do to fix this, 'cause I don't want to restart my laptop every time I forget to plug in the mouse.

You might try clearing the USB history, https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-the-Record-of-USB-Plug-in-Equipment, in case a bad record is causing an issue. It does no harm to clear all, though when a device is first plugged in, it might take a few seconds to configure it.
